# Can I fake a user interaction for beforeunload event to work in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, events, onbeforeunload, onbeforeload

Since beforeunload event is not triggered unless if there is a user interaction, is it possible to fake the interaction.

I tried having a dummy click or focus on input using jQuery but still beforeunload is not triggered. Is there any other way to trigger it?